# Как можно получить вчерашнее время в формате RFC3339 на Python?

Tags: python, дата, datetime

Всем привет, есть код, который выводит вчерашнее время, но я без понятия как его можно перевести в формат RFC3339. Буду благодарен за помощь!

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

n = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1) #(находит вчерашнее время)

print(n.isoformat())
```

> #2023-03-28T02:00:00-05:00  (образец)
>
> #2023-03-28T20:09:05.062406 (вывод из программы)

Comment: Просто надо таймзону добавить https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556398/generate-rfc-3339-timestamp-in-python

Comment: Это не решает проблему, на выходе я получаю >> 2023-03-29T21:07:41+05:00, а должен получать >> 2023-03-29T23:07:00-05:00

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот вам `-5`, просто зону надо соответствующую взять:

```py
import datetime
import pytz

dt = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
utc_dt = pytz.timezone('US/Central').localize(dt)
print(utc_dt.isoformat())
```

Вывод:

```
2023-03-28T19:26:06.334592-05:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
import datatime


n = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(n.isoformat())
```

Comment: Не, не работает. Проблема в том, что на выходе мы получаем стандартный формат времени "ISO 8601 UTC", а не RFC3339